# mysql complex query to count and sum on same tabel

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query which is really very slow(takes about 30-45 mins) and get stuck sometime, and 500 error generates which is not good for application...

```
SELECT id, account_number, email, referred_by, dnt,
                             (SELECT count(*)
                              FROM tbl.registrations t2
                              WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
                             ) AS level1,
                             (SELECT count(*)
                              FROM  tbl.registrations t2 join
                                    tbl.registrations t3
                                    on t3.referred_by = t2.account_number
                              WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
                             ) AS level2,
                             (SELECT count(*)
                              FROM tbl.registrations t2 join
                                    tbl.registrations t3
                                    on t3.referred_by = t2.account_number join
                                    tbl.registrations t4
                                    on t4.referred_by = t3.account_number
                              WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
                             ) AS level3
                          FROM tbl.registrations t1 GROUP BY id;
```

We have about 35000 rows in this table and db structure as follows...

```
| id | account_number  | referred_by  |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 | ac01            | 5            |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  2 | ac02            | 5            |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  3 | ac03            | 4            |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
```

Calculation of level1, level2 and level3 as following...

```
total_referred - total number of members referred by account_number
total_reffered2 - total number of members that THEY(all accounts referred by account_number) all referred
total_reffered3 - total number of members that referred by all members of total_reffered2
```

For example

If every member always had 10 referrals, then...

```
level1 = 10
level2 = 100
level3 = 1000
```

Please check what am i doing wrong? Please help me to rewrite this query or optimize, btw i already tried adding INDEX. thanks

Comment: If the `id` is unique in your registration table, then the `group by` is unnecessary.  Try removing that to see how it affects performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nothing i already tried that, nothing happened! This query is really slow, and throws timeout error

Comment: Did you try running EXPLAIN on your statement? Just to get an idea what is going on (how query optimizer is approaching the problem), and where to search for optimization.

Comment: @Zagor23 sorry i didn't try that, can you help me to do that?

Comment: @Zagor23 do you want output of EXPLAIN

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the EXPLAIN just yet. Instead provide DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH your desired result.

Comment: it provides correct results, but problem with query speed and optimization.

Comment: Just to confirm... Is the "Account Number" unique too as a direct correlation to the "id" column?  ie. There would never be another account number "ac02" other than the id=2 instance.  Also, can you provide some more sample data?  Finally, your Referred_by appears as an integer and would appear should be grouped by the "ID" and not the account number as account number is string and wouldn't match.

Comment: @DRapp Yes Account Number is unique too

Comment: It appears you are trying to get a hierarchical summary of referrals like a pyramid scheme, or organizational chart where 1 person is responsible for x people... and those x people are responsible for y people, so the total responsible for person 1 is the sum of all x + all y people (but referrals in this reference).  Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample via [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6381/1).  I entered a list of 40 entries with the corresponding ID that referred them showing the hierarchy of the following...

```
(hierarchy for 1)      (hierarchy for 2)   (hierarchy for 3)
    1                      2                   3
       4                      13                  21
          5                       14              22
          6                       15                  23
             31               16                         39
             32               17                         40
          7                       18                  24
       8                              35              25
          9                           36              26
          10                          37          27
          11                          38              28
             33                   19                  29
             34                   20                  30
          12
```

The SQLFiddle query creates 3 columns based on any possible referred by reference.  If an ID had no accounts referred by their ID, they won't have a value and needs to be resolved with COALESCE to prevent nulls..

```
select r.*,
       coalesce( presum.lvl1Cnt, 0 ) as Lvl1Total,
       coalesce( presum.lvl1cnt + presum.lvl2cnt, 0 ) as Lvl2Total,
       coalesce( presum.lvl1cnt + presum.lvl2cnt + presum.lvl3cnt, 0 ) as Lvl3Total
   from
      registrations r
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT 
                    r1.referred_by, 
                    count(distinct r1.id) as Lvl1Cnt,
                    count(distinct r2.id) as Lvl2Cnt,
                    count(distinct r3.id) as Lvl3Cnt
                 from 
                    registrations r1 
                       LEFT JOIN registrations r2 
                          ON r1.id = r2.referred_by 
                          LEFT JOIN registrations r3 
                             ON r2.id = r3.referred_by 
                 group by 
                    r1.referred_by ) presum
      ON r.id = presum.referred_by
```

The presum inner query is done once across the board.  I would just make sure you have and index on the table on (referred_by, id) to help optimize the grouping by referred_by ID value